# T-test with grouping variable

Tags: r, statistics, grouping

I've got a data frame with 36 variables and 74 observations. I'd like to make a two sample paired ttest of 35 variables by 1 grouping variable (with two levels).

For example: the data frame contains "age" "body weight" and "group" variables.
Now I suppose I can do the ttest for each variable with this code:

`t.test(age~group)`

But, is there a way to test all the 35 variables with one code, and not one by one?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: you could loop / *ply over every column...

Comment: There is a way but it is NOT with a `t.test`. Do some reading on multiple comparisons. If you have no domain knowledge about the relationships of 'group' with these variables, then exploratory analysis could be done with binary logistic regression, but try to avoid the stepwise procedures that SAS and SPSS encourages.

Comment: I should have asked you rather than Swen. Is this really a "paired study"? How was the pairing done?

Comment: @DWin I think it's paired, see the comment below

Comment: Then strike my suggestion of logistic regression as well.

Answer (score 5):

An example data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(age = rnorm(10, 30), body = rnorm(10, 30), 
                  weight = rnorm(10, 30), group = gl(2,5))
```

You can use `lapply`:

```
lapply(dat[1:3], function(x) 
                   t.test(x ~ dat$group, paired = TRUE, na.action = na.pass))
```

In the command above, `1:3` represents the numbers of the columns including the variables. The argument `paired = TRUE` is necessary to perform a paired t-test.

Comment: Two questions: Did you test this code with unequal sized groups? Why would this be considered a "paired" test?

Comment: @DWin 1) Yes, I tested the code. 2) The OP asked for a paired test. I don't know the actual meaning of the `group` variable used here.

Comment: @DWin BTW: I agree that a t-test does not appear appropriate for the described task. Unfortunately, the OP didn't clarify the meaning of `group` and the hypotheses.

Comment: OK. I missed the word "paired". But one generally does either a "two-sample" t-test or "paired" t-test. Given the other suggestions of deficiencies in statistical knowledge displayed, perhaps it would be more responsible to pin down the questioner about what the real data situation is and what hypotheses are being examined.

Comment: @DWin Of course the code doesn't work with unequal sized groups. In this case, `paired = FALSE` has to be used.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Sorry, I gave you too little information. I need to test the change in some variables after a treatment (grouping variable = before/after treatment). I think the paired T test is appropriate, do you agree? By the way, the code seems good for me, but I cannot handle missing values ("Error in complete.cases(x,y):not all arguments have the same length") Any suggestion?

Comment: @user3097087 A paired test is appropriate for before/after treatment data. I added an additional argument to `t.test` to handle `NA`s. See the update.

Answer (score 5):

Sven has provided you with a great way of implementing what you wanted to have implemented. I, however, want to warn you about the statistical aspect of what you are doing.

Recall that if you are using the standard confidence level of 0.05, this means that for each t-test performed, you have a 5% chance of committing Type 1 error (incorrectly rejecting the null hypothesis.) By the laws of probability, running 35 individual t-tests compounds your probability of committing type 1 error by a factor of 35, or more exactly:

Pr(Type 1 Error) = 1 - (0.95)^35 = 0.834

Meaning that you have about an 83.4% chance of falsely rejecting a null hypothesis. Basically what this means is that, by running so many T-tests, there is a very high probability that at least one of your T-tests is going to provide an incorrect result.

Just FYI.

Comment: Too big for a comment, and very important for anyone reading this thread to consider. +1