# How do I add a by group to a t.test?

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I would like to look at my t-tests by a group called  fish species. How would I include this in the code?

```
t.test(Delta.C.parasitef[Parasite.species =="Anilocra"], 
DeltaC.parasitem[Parasite.species =="Anilocra"]) 

#In the above code I want to only look at the specified values belonging to a a 
particular fish species, and I have 4 different ones.
```

Comment: It is much easier for people to try to help you if you include the data you are starting with (you can create this using `dput`).

Comment: Possible help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168378/applying-two-sample-t-test-comparing-multiple-groups-in-two-categories, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553995/t-test-with-grouping-variable

Comment: `t-test()` has a `subset` argument, have you tried using that?